# Connection to MSSQL database for secure login in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sql-server, ios, ios4

I want to make an app having financial Transactions for iPhone.So, my first target is to make a login page(and that's where my problem starts):-

The Admin or customer Details are stored in MSSQL DB.Now, when the client enters his username and password in my app, i want to verify these Credentials. So how can i do this?

Acc. to my little knowledge, i cannot connect to the DB directly, I need some web service or something as a middleware(but don't know what).I cannot parse the url directly to check the credentials as it will not be safe.Did we have to Encrypt the Credentials of client and if yes then how can i retrieve and verify the Login?

Any Sample, Links or anything will be helpful.

Comment: Where did your database come from? Is there already a site set up? How will you be making the transactions? Will you be using a payment gateway? Are you familiar with Authorize.net?

Comment: the server side is in ASP and i have to use MSSQL Database. Yes, there is a site set up. And yes we need to use a payment gateway. and I am not familiar with Authorize.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a .net site with a login.aspx web service page where you will handle authentication for the app. Make sure to get a HTTPS/SSL cert set up on your site as well.

Call me overly cautious, but I hate the idea of direct web server database access from a client app, I always like a middle layer of control/protection.

**Edit**

for example, you app can make server calls similar to this (using POST of course): `yoursite.com/webservice/Login.aspx?username=chucknorris&password=somepassword&appkey=679384820473487746`

Then on your Login.aspx page (or other pages for that matter) you would check for the POST variables (username, password, etc) and ask the database if they match. If they do then have the page return a success message, or do whatever additional processing you desire.

On multiple page requests within a certain amount of time, you can optionally use session states or go the more RESTful type of route, both are easily researched via Google.

POST + SSL is a must for basic security measures.

Comment: Sorry to say, but i am not getting your point clearly. See i have made an app previously also regarding database Fetching. In that i have made an Database in Oracle 11g, Used J2ME for making servlets, using these servlets i am generating XMLS from the database and through my app, i was just parsing these XML's for Login verifications. but now i cann't do this as we can use Urls to parse directly as it will not be safe, i think so :D

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, i think i got this now :P. Let me know whether i am correct or not.ok ? I will make a .Net site with Login.aspx. Through my app i will send the client Username and password to the .Net Site which will check the Validation on Database and generate the <success> or <failure> tag. I will parse these tags and then continue the App?

Comment: One more query is going in my mind regarding my just previous comment that if suppose multiple people using my app simultaneously and how will the .NET page will work regarding generating that <success> tag...?

Comment: You are on the right path. There shouldn't be an issue with multiple people using their own instance of your app to log in since web servers are designed to handle such as thing.

Comment: Sorry for the Late. Actually i google it and found that there is one more way that by using API's. We can generate Api's Using some websites or create our own. You can visit this site for Trial www.Kumulos.com